# Angular 6 + Routes Resolver = 404 page in production

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, angular6, angular-routerlink

I am new to Angular Community coming from rails ; I am working on a site where I can post case studies of my clients website. So far I am loving angular but I am running into an issue that worries me a bit. The issue that I cant seem to use hyperlinks to reference any of the projects. For example if you click on **[this](https://www.2150design.com)** the application will return a 404 status but if you start from the **[root page](https://www.2150design.com)** everything will run no problem.

**Solutions I have tried**

1. Adding a resolver to the route to fetch the data before loading the
   page; it works but still no hyperlink.

Can anyone help me figure out what I am missing or doing wrong;

Below is my code; Any help would be appreciated

1. **Project.service.ts**

```js
    import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
    import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
    import { map,  } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Project } from '../../models/project';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Post } from '../post';
    
    
    
    
    @Injectable()
    
    export class ProjectService {
    
        ProjectListRef: Observable<any[]>;
        featuredProjectList: Observable<any[]>;
        posts: Array<Post>;
   
    
        constructor( private database: AngularFirestore, private http: HttpClient) {
            // Link For All Projects Page
            const allProjectsListLink = this.database.collection<Project>('projects', ref => ref.orderBy('company_name'));
    
    
    
            // Link For Featured Project Page
            const featuredProjectsListLink = this.database.collection<Project>('projects', ref => ref.limit(5));
    
    
    
this.ProjectListRef = allProjectsListLink.snapshotChanges()
            // using map pipe
            .pipe(map( actions => {
                return actions.map(a => {
                    // Get Document Data
                    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Project;

                    // Get Document Id

                    const id = a.payload.doc.id;

                    return {id, ...data};

                });
            }));
    
      this.featuredProjectList = featuredProjectsListLink.snapshotChanges()
      // using map pipe
      .pipe(map( actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
      // Get Document Data
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Project;

      // Get Document Id

      const id = a.payload.doc.id;

      return {id, ...data};

      });
      }));


      }


        getAllProjects() {
            return this.ProjectListRef;
        }
    
        getFeaturedProjects() {
            return this.featuredProjectList;
        }
    
        getProject(id: string) {
            console.log(id);
            return this.database.collection('projects').doc(id)
            .ref.get().then( doc => doc.data() );
          }
    
    }
```

2. **Project.component.ts**

```js
        import { Component, OnInit, Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
                import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
                import {  tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
                import { ProjectService } from '../../app/services/project.service';
                import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
                import { Project } from '../../models/project';
                import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
    
            @Injectable()
            
            @Component({
              selector: 'app-project-page',
              templateUrl: './project-page.component.html',
              styleUrls: ['./project-page.component.scss']
            })
            export class ProjectPageComponent implements OnInit {
            
              project: Project;
              projectId: any;
              projectRef: any;
            
            
              constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any, private router: Router,
                          private route: ActivatedRoute,
                          public database: AngularFirestore,
                          private projectService: ProjectService
                        ) {
            
                  }
            
            
              ngOnInit() {
            
                  // print out the data from the route resolver
                  this.route.data.pipe(
                    tap(console.log))
                    .subscribe(
                      data => this.project = data['project']
                  );
            
              }
            
              goToWebsite(url) {
                this.document.location.href = url;
              }
            
            
            
            }
```

```
 3. **ProjectResolver.ts**
```

```js
import { ProjectService } from './../../app/services/project.service';
import { Project } from './../project';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    
    
    @Injectable()
    
    export class ProjectResolver implements Resolve<Project> {
    
        constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) {
    
        }
    
        resolve(
                route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Project>|Promise<any> {
                return this.projectService.getProject(route.params['id']);
                }
    
    
    }
```

4. **Application Routes**

```js
import { AddLeadPageComponent } from './add-lead-page/add-lead-page.component';
import { GoogleAdsPageComponent } from './google-ads-page/google-ads-page.component';
import { WebAppsPageComponent } from './web-apps-page/web-apps-page.component';
import { BrandedWebsitesPageComponent } from './branded-websites-page/branded-websites-page.component';
import { ServiceOverviewPageComponent } from './service-overview-page/service-overview-page.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';
import { AboutPageComponent } from './about-page/about-page.component';
import { BlogPageComponent } from './blog-page/blog-page.component';
import { WebServicesPageComponent } from './web-services-page/web-services-page.component';
import { SEMPageComponent } from './sempage/sempage.component';
import { ContactPageComponent } from './contact-page/contact-page.component';
import { AllProjectsPageComponent } from './all-projects-page/all-projects-page.component';
import { ResearchServicePageComponent } from './research-service-page/research-service-page.component';
import { ProjectPageComponent } from './project-page/project-page.component';
import { TeamPageComponent } from './team-page/team-page.component';
import { NewProjectComponent } from './new-project/new-project.component';
import { DigitalMarketingPageComponent } from './digital-marketing-page/digital-marketing-page.component';
import { ProjectResolver } from '../models/resolvers/project.resolver';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomePageComponent},
  { path: 'about', component: AboutPageComponent},
  { path: 'blog', component: BlogPageComponent},
  { path: 'team', component: TeamPageComponent},
  { path: 'portfolio', component: AllProjectsPageComponent},
  { path: 'services', component: ServiceOverviewPageComponent},
  { path: 'project/:id', component: ProjectPageComponent, resolve: { project: ProjectResolver}},
  { path: 'brand-strategy', component: ResearchServicePageComponent},
  { path: 'digital-strategy', component: DigitalMarketingPageComponent},
  { path: 'custom-websites', component: BrandedWebsitesPageComponent},
  { path: 'web-apps', component: WebAppsPageComponent},
  { path: 'google-ads', component: GoogleAdsPageComponent},
  { path: 'web-design-development', component: WebServicesPageComponent},
  { path: 'search-engine-marketing', component: SEMPageComponent},
  { path: 'start-new-project', component: ContactPageComponent},
  { path: 'new-project', component: NewProjectComponent},
// post trial
  { path: 'posts/add', component: AddLeadPageComponent},
  { path: 'posts/add/:id', component: AddLeadPageComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
            RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})
            ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any error in your angular code. The problem you are facing is that the urls are not being rewritten to index.html. You need to configure this in your Firebase settings(firebase.json). This is the easiest and most common configuration:

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I wish I had the reputation to give you a thumbs up. It worked. You have put an end to a 48 hour search! Thank you indefinitely.